# How to log key data for iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to test a text entry application on iphone and need to log users' key data. For example, when the user tapped a specific key and how often the user tapped a specific key.
Is there a way to log such data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the text*:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText delegate for every text field and text view, and count up all the changes looking at the replacement text to determine the input key.